# How to remove group of rows in R based on sum of 3 columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm a newby in the R world.

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: location (with several factor levels each containing several rows), condition1, condition2, condition3 (those 3 columns have integer values).
I want to delete the location factors whose sum of the three condition columns is 0.

I don't want to delete each row that the sum of the three columns is 0 (that is simple and I have already done) because I want to keep the rows whit the sums=0 if it is not the fact that in each row of the location group is 0 the result.

Hope that this sounds understandable to someone...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show few lines of your dataset and the expected outptu as the description is somewhat confusing.  Perhaps `df1[rowSums(df1[paste0("condition", 1:3)])!=0,]`

Comment: I don't know how to insert an image with the gry background in which I can show you the data.frame but I can insert here the codes

        
location <- c(rep(c("c01", "c02", "c03", "c04", "c05"), each = 5))   ;
condition1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,5,1,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0)    ;
condition2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,5,6,0,5,0,0,4,7,3,8,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,5,0,7)    ;
condition3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,0,4,7,9,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,5)   ;

my_df <- data.frame(location, condition1, condition2, condition3)

Comment: Have you tried `my_df[rowSums(my_df[paste0("condition", 1:3)])!=0,]`

Comment: it gives me an error:
Error in `[.data.table`(my_df, paste0("condition", 1:3)) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.

Comment: Based on the example you showed, it is not giving me any error.  Okay, so I thought you have a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`

Comment: yes it is a data.frame

Comment: Your error shows that it is `data.table`

Comment: I only managed to understand your question after reading it several times. In future, you may wish to provide examples of your desired output to help others to understand your question. @akrun has been remarkably patient and helpful.

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to remove the groups 'location' where all the values are 0, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(my_df)` - from the comments, it seems like the OP's dataset is `data.table`), grouped by 'location', we specify the `.SDcols` as the 'condition' columns, get the row wise `sum` of the `.SD` using `Reduce` for each 'location', get the `sum` of the `vector`, check whether it is not equal to 0, find the rowindex of the logical vector with `.I`, extract the column that has the row index (`$V1`) and subset the rows of 'my_df'.

```
setDT(my_df)[my_df[, .I[sum(Reduce(`+`, .SD))!=0] , by = location, 
                      .SDcols = condition1:condition3]$V1]
#    location condition1 condition2 condition3
# 1:      c02          1          5          4
# 2:      c02          1          6          3
# 3:      c02          0          0          0
# 4:      c02          2          5          0
# 5:      c02          5          0          0
# 6:      c03          1          0          0
# 7:      c03          0          4          4
# 8:      c03          0          7          7
# 9:      c03          5          3          9
#10:      c03          4          8          2
#11:      c05          0          3          0
#12:      c05          0          0          0
#13:      c05          5          5          5
#14:      c05          1          0          1
#15:      c05          0          7          5
```

Another variation of the above is

```
setDT(my_df)[my_df[,  .I[Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, sum))!=0], by = location, 
                    .SDcols = condition1:condition3]$V1]
```

Or `unlist` the `.SD`, get the `sum`, check whether it is not equal to 0 and as mentioned above extracting the row index column will be used for subsetting the rows.

```
setDT(my_df)[my_df[,  .I[sum(unlist(.SD))!=0], by = location]$V1]
```

#### data

```
location <- c(rep(c("c01", "c02", "c03", "c04", "c05"), each = 5))
condition1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,5,1,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0)
condition2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,5,6,0,5,0,0,4,7,3,8,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,5,0,7)
condition3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0,0,0,4,7,9,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,5)
my_df <- data.frame(location, condition1, condition2, condition3)
```

Comment: Not exactly.
in this way you delete every rows in which the sum of the three condition is 0, but I want to keep all the c02 and c05 rows even if in those groups (c02 and c05) there is a row in which the sum of the three columns is = 0.

Comment: @Wildebeest  THis is the reason I said that your post is confusing.  Do you wnt to keep only C02 and c05 rows??

Comment: Yes I know it's confusing, but I don't know how to explain in a better way. I'm sorry.
By the way, I don't want to keep only the c02 and c05 rows

Comment: @Wildebeest  Updated the post

Comment: @akrun: I think OP wants to remove rows only if every row for a given group sums to zero.

Comment: The Update seems working fine thank you! :)
But the dataset that I gave you is just an example. Isn't there a way to do it without specify c("c02", "c05")??
In the other datasets that I have to go through there are 48 different locations and the 0s change between every dataset.
And what if there will be also other columns instead only those four?

Comment: @Wildebeest  As WeihuangWong mentioned, you may need the group sums to zero,  in that case, I updated the post again.

Comment: Can you try to help me with the case in which there are other columns? those will not be involved in the calculations, though.

Comment: @Wildebeest That is the reason why we specify `.SDcols`

Comment: I tried but if you add another column to that dataset, after I use the function you gave me that column will be deleted. And I want to keep all the columns.
I should have told you from the beginning maybe, I'm sorry...

Comment: @Wildebeest  Updated the post again.  Now, this should keep all the columns.